# Browser detection from server with Java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm caching different browsers with the following code, I can't cache the specific one.

Can someone give me some advice?

```
if (user.contains("msie")) {
                    String substring = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")).split(";")[0];
                    browser = substring.split(" ")[0].replace("MSIE", "IE") + "-"+ substring.split(" ")[1];
                } else if (user.contains("safari") && user.contains("version")) {
                    browser = (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Safari")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[0]+ "-"+ (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Version")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[1];
                } else if (user.contains("opr") || user.contains("opera")) {
                    if (user.contains("opera"))
                        browser = (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Opera")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[0]+ "-"+ (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Version")).split(" ")[0]).split("/")[1];
                    else if (user.contains("opr"))
                        browser = ((userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("OPR")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-")).replace("OPR","Opera");
                } else if (user.contains("chrome")) {
                    browser = (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-");
                } else if ((user.indexOf("mozilla/36.0") > -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("netscape6") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/35.0") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/34.0") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/33.1") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/33.0") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/32.0") != -1)
                        || (user.indexOf("mozilla/31.0") != -1)) {

                    browser = "Netscape-?";

                } else if (user.contains("firefox")) {
                    browser = (userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split(" ")[0]).replace("/", "-");
                } else if (user.contains("rv")) {
                    browser = "IE";
                } else {
                    browser = "UnKnown, More-Info: " + userAgent;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                browser = "Exception: " + userAgent;
            }
```

Comment: How do you expect this to work? you are testing the browser on a machine you are not working on.

Comment: it is tested on production.

Comment: Vladislav: the environment is irrelevant. this code runs (as you said) on the server, while you are trying to determine the browser on the client.
You'll need some client-side scripting for that.

Comment: What is the relationship between these two variables, `user` and `userAgent`? I know the `USER-AGENT` header field but you are constantly switching between these variables `userAgent` and `user` which seem to have no relationship. Further note that your entire code is wrapped in an `if(user.contains("msie")) {` which precludes all other cases…

Comment: String browserDetails = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
String userAgent = browserDetails;
String user = userAgent.toLowerCase()

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need server side code, You can easily do it in javascript.

```
function detect() {
                var browser;
                var version;                
                var platform = navigator.platform;

                if (platform == "iPad" || platform == "iPhone" || platform == "iPod" || platform == "iPod touch") { // For iPhones iPads and iPods

                    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();

                    var chromeIndex = userAgent.indexOf("CRIOS");
                    var opera = userAgent.indexOf("OPIOS");
                    var ucIndex = userAgent.indexOf("UCBROWSER");
                    var coast = userAgent.indexOf("COAST");
                    var mercury = userAgent.indexOf("MERCURY");

                    var safari = userAgent.indexOf("SAFARI");
                    var webkit = userAgent.indexOf("APPLEWEBKIT");

                    // Chrome detection
                    if(chromeIndex > 0) {
                        browser = "chrome";

                        var arr = userAgent.split("CRIOS/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    }
                    // Safari detection
                    else if(opera < 0 && ucIndex < 0 && coast < 0 && mercury < 0 && safari > 0 && webkit > 0) {
                        browser = "safari";

                        var arr = userAgent.split("APPLEWEBKIT/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    } else {
                        browser = "unknown";
                        version = -1;
                    }

                } else if(platform == "Win32" || platform == "MacIntel") { // For windows and mac

                    // Browser detection
                    var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
                    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
                    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'; // Firefox 1.0+
                    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
                    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
                    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera; // Chrome 1+
                    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6


                    if (isOpera) {
                        browser = "opera";
                    } else if (isFirefox) {
                        browser = "firefox";
                    } else if (isChrome) {
                        browser = "chrome";
                    } else if (isIE) {
                        browser = "ie";
                    } else if (isSafari) {
                        browser = "safari";
                    } else {
                        browser = "unknown";
                    }

                    if (browser == "firefox") {
                        var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("Firefox/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    } else if (browser == "chrome") {
                        var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("Chrome/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    } else if (browser == "ie") {
                        var v1 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MISE");
                        var v2 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:");

                        if(v1 > 0) {
                            var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("MSIE ");
                            arr = arr[1].split(".");
                            version = arr[0];
                        } else if(v2 > 0){
                            var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("rv:");
                            arr = arr[1].split(".");
                            version = arr[0];
                        } else {
                            version = 11;
                        }
                    } else if (browser == "safari") {
                        var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("AppleWebKit/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    } else if (browser == "opera") {
                        var arr = navigator.userAgent.split("OPR/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];
                    } else if (browser == "unknown") {
                        version = -1;
                    }

                } else if(platform == "Android" || platform == "Linux armv7l") { // For android
                    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

                    var chromeIndex = userAgent.indexOf("Chrome");
                    var opera = userAgent.indexOf("OPR");
                    var ucIndex = userAgent.indexOf("UCBrowser");
                    var coast = userAgent.indexOf("Coast");
                    var firefox = userAgent.indexOf("Firefox");

                    // Chrome detection
                    if(chromeIndex > 0 && opera < 0 && ucIndex < 0 && coast < 0) {
                        browser = "chrome";

                        var arr = userAgent.split("Chrome/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];

                    } else if(firefox > 0) { // Firefox detection
                        browser = "firefox";

                        var arr = userAgent.split("Firefox/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];

                    } else if(opera > 0) { // Opera detection
                        browser = "opera";

                        var arr = userAgent.split("OPR/");
                        arr = arr[1].split(".");
                        version = arr[0];

                    } else { // Unknown browser
                        browser = "unknown";
                        version = -1;
                    }

                } else { // For other platforms
                    version = -1;
                    browser = "other_platform";
                }
```

I have used this script in my app, you can find this helpful.

Comment: is there a code to detect and operating system?thanks soumitri  pattnaik

Comment: soumitri pattnaik how you send this browser info to server?

Comment: You can set them in cookie, and you can read the cookies from server.